# Asp.Net SecuritySwitch & SSL Load balancer

Tags: asp.net, securityswitch

I am trying to use SecuritySwitch (http://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/) on an asp.net website.

On secure pages I get an error of:  *This web page has a redirect loop*

I assume that SecuritySwitch is trying to detect if the request is https and redirecting if it is not. As my host uses some kind of SSL load balancer which uses the http header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO to detect if the request is https I think that it is not recognising that the request as valid and trying to redirect again.

Can anyone think of a way to solve this?

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. I am using SecuritySwitch with an asp.net website hosted on appharbor. There is a help from appharbor, but I cannot figure out where to integrate their solution when using SecuritySwitch. http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/workaround-for-generating-absolute-urls-without-port-number

Comment: The instructions in the link you give aren't that helpful.  You need to ask them how to identify the protocol used, not the URL as this article describes.  Its likely their load balanced router will be filling in a http header you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no solution to this, but the good people on the project released a new version within 2days of a request being made making it possible.

SecuritySwitch (http://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/)
Highly recommended!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Could you expand on how did you finally solved the problem? Otherwise this can't be considered the Answer.

Comment: It turned out to be a bug within securityswitch.  They fixed it and released a new version.